# How to sort a 2D array in C where each column is of a different type?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, struct

In my code below I have a 5x4 array that I would like to be able to sort first by its 0th column (sku of int type) and if there are equalities then 1st column (plant, a string: Ex. CA72 > CA70, CA will always be in front of those two integers, 7 and 2 in this case) and finally by its 2nd column (age of double type).

Unfortunately I am unable with this current code to even parse the data into the struct correctly. I've never used a struct before so my question is two fold: where am I going wrong in initializing the structure, and lastly how do I get it to sort one column at a time as mentioned above?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct st_ex {
    int sku;
    char plant[4];
    char age_code[10];
    int qty;
   // char product[16];
   // float price;
};

int comp_sku(const void *a, const void *b) { //qsort struct comparision function (sku int field)
    struct st_ex *ia = (struct st_ex *)a;
    struct st_ex *ib = (struct st_ex *)b;
    return (int)(ia->sku - ib->sku);
    /* int comparison: returns negative if b > a
    and positive if a > b. */
}

int comp_plant(const void *a, const void *b) { //qsort struct comparison function (plant C-string field)
    struct st_ex *ia = (struct st_ex *)a;
    struct st_ex *ib = (struct st_ex *)b;
    return strcmp(ia->plant, ib->plant);
    /* strcmp functions works exactly as expected from
    comparison function */
}

int comp_age(const void *a, const void *b) { //qsort struct comparison function (age double field)
    struct st_ex *ia = (struct st_ex *)a;
    struct st_ex *ib = (struct st_ex *)b;
    return strcmp(ia->age_code, ib->age_code);
}


void print_array(struct st_ex *array, size_t len){
    size_t i;
    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
        printf("[ SKU: %i \t Plant: %s \t Code: %s \t Qty: %i ]\n", array[i].sku, array[i].plant, array[i].age_code, array[i].qty);
    puts("--");
}

void sort_struct(void) {
    struct st_ex structs[] = {{"4010","CA50","15834.0261","5"},
                              {"4010","CA50","15876.0261","6"},
                              {"4010","CA52","14834.0261","7"},
                              {"4200","CA72","16028.3085","9"},
                              {"4001","CA72","15022.0001","9"}};

    size_t s_len = sizeof(structs) / sizeof(struct st_ex);

    puts("*** Original array...");
    print_array(structs, s_len); //Print original array

    puts("*** Sorted by sku...");
    qsort(structs, s_len, sizeof(struct st_ex), comp_sku);
    print_array(structs, s_len); //Print array sorted by sku

    puts("*** Sorted by plant...");
    qsort(structs, s_len, sizeof(struct st_ex), comp_plant);
    print_array(structs, s_len); //Print array sorted by plant

    /** How do I sort by sku first and then plant? (provided the sku's are equal)*/
}

void main() {
    sort_struct();
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated, thank you!

Note: Here's what I've changed now but can't get it to sort through the doubles still:

```
int comp_sku(const void *a, const void *b) { //qsort struct comparision function (sku int field)
    struct st_ex *ia = (struct st_ex *)a;
    struct st_ex *ib = (struct st_ex *)b;
    if (ia->sku == ib->sku && ia->age_code == ib->age_code){
        return strcmp(ia->age_code, ib->age_code);
    }
    else if(ia->sku == ib->sku){
        return strcmp(ia->plant, ib->plant);
    }
    else{return (ia->sku-ib->sku);}
}
```

Follow-up edit:

So if I wanted to, for example, perform this quick sort on the same data set but this time imported using .csv file that would read just like the matrix above [4001, CA87, 22345.234, 48][...] x 100,000. I've tried to change the code to fit my new needs but the new naming of the structure without defining it's size is proving problematic. What am I doing wrong?

```
void main() {
    char           buffer[1024], *line;
    struct st_ex   input;
    unsigned long  lineno = 0UL;
    FILE* inputdoc = fopen("input/old_input.csv", "r");

    while (1) {
        line = fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, inputdoc);
            if (!line)
            break;

        lineno++;

            if (sscanf(line, "%d, %4s, %10s, %d", &input.sku, &input.plant, &input.age, &input.qty) != 4) {
            fprintf(stderr,"Cannot parse line %lu.\n", lineno);
            break;
        }

        /* Do something with 'struct st_ex input'. */

    };

    size_t s_len = sizeof(input) / sizeof(struct st_ex);
    puts("*** Original array...\n");
    //print_array(input, s_len); //Print original array

    puts("\n*** Sorted by sku, plant, age.\n\n");
    qsort(input, s_len, sizeof(struct st_ex), comp_sku_plant_age);
    print_array(input, s_len); //Print array sorted by sku
}
```

Comment: 1) `char plant[4];
    char age_code[10];` --> `char plant[5];
    char age_code[11];` 2) `{"4010","CA50","15834.0261","5"}` --> `{4010,"CA50","15834.0261", 5}`

Comment: Sort by SKUs, if you get 2 that match then instead of returning 0 from the compare function look at the strings to compute the return value. I.e - you modify the `comp_sku` function.  `if (ia->sku == ib->sku) return strcmp(ia->plant, ib->plant); else return (ia->sku-ib->sku);`

Comment: Your terminology is confused or confusing.  You seem to be describing an array (probably one-dimensional) of a structure type rather than a 2D array.  All else apart, all arrays in C are homogeneous; they only contain elements of one type — not multiple types.  (You can sometimes play games with pointers and things so it seems like you store different types in an array, but actually you don't — and it's way more complex than what you're dealing with.)  Your question title should be more like 'How do I sort an array of a structure type with different criteria for different members?'

Comment: Thanks bluepixy, now reading correctly. 

enhzfelp, I've made your changes and it now works great but in trying to replicate that with the double values I am not able to get it to work. I put my changes above.

Comment: Jonathan, you're right I think my limited knowledge here is limiting me as I've never done anything like this in C. Should I reconsider my entire strategy for dealing with this mix of strings and numbers? Or is there a way to make the above table work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You have an array of structures, something like

```
struct st_ex {
    int    sku;
    char   plant[5]; /* 4 characters + string terminating '\0' at end */
    double age;
};
```

If you want to sort by `sku` field, breaking ties by the `plant` field, and breaking the ties there by the `age` field, use

```
int compare_st_ex(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2)
{
    const struct st_ex *const ref1 = (const struct st_ex *)ptr1;
    const struct st_ex *const ref2 = (const struct st_ex *)ptr2;
    int                       plant;

    /* Compare 'sku' fields. */
    if (ref1->sku < ref2->sku)
        return -1;
    else
    if (ref1->sku > ref2->sku)
        return +1;

    /* Compare 'plant' fields. */
    plant = strncmp(ref1->plant, ref2->plant, sizeof ref1->plant);
    if (plant)
        return plant;

    /* Compare 'age' fields. */
    if (ref1->age < ref2->age)
        return -1;
    else
    if (ref1->age > ref2->age)
        return +1;

    /* The two are essentially equal. */
    return 0;
}
```

Above, I use `if (foo)` as shorthand for `if (foo != 0)`.

See how each field comparison only returns if the fields differ? If the fields compare equal, we move to the next field (that breaks ties).

If you have a file with one record per line, use a loop to read the line, then parse the fields into structure members using e.g. [`sscanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html):

```
    char           buffer[1024], *line;
    struct st_ex   one;
    unsigned long  lineno = 0UL;

    while (1) {

        line = fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
        if (!line)
            break;

        lineno++;

        if (sscanf(line, "%d %4s %lf", &one.sku, one.plant, &one.age) != 3) {
            fprintf(stderr,"Cannot parse line %lu.\n", lineno);
            break;
        }

        /* Do something with 'struct st_ex one'. */

    };
```

The `%d` scan pattern converts an `int`; `%4s` converts a word or token, a string without whitespace, of up to four characters (and requires at least five characters of space reserved, to include the string-terminating nul byte, `\0`); and `%lf` converts a `double`. The return value is the number of successful conversions.

Note that it is important to specify the length of the string the `plant` field can handle, and to remember that strings need a terminating nul byte (`'\0'`) at end; thus, the number supplied in the pattern is usually one less than the size allocated for. If you do not specify the length, and the line happens to have a long string there, the scanf family of functions will happily overwrite memory outside the field, leading to crashes or strange errors. So Don't Do That, Ever, even if your lecturer says it does not matter. (Because if they do, they're wrong and they should be ashamed of themselves: it just leads to frustrating problems, and is easy enough to understand and avoid.)

Finally, remember that you can assign structure-type variables as if they were normal basic variable types. That is, if you had `struct st_ex foo[5];`, it is perfectly okay to write e.g. `foo[0] = one;` in the snippet above.

Comment: Thanks Nominal! I believe I understand everything you've said up until that last paragraph. Does that mean that I could parse a .csv file using that method? (I've tried something of that nature in an edit of the main question).

Comment: @MatthewR: The final paragraph is just a reminder that you do not need to assign the fields separately, you can assign the entire structure at once. For CSV, I recommend a slightly different approach; rather than use `fgets()` to read a line, write two functions: `ftoken()`, which reads a CSV field (if any), and properly handles quoted fields (including embedded newlines and commas) and escaped quotes, but will not pass into the next record; and `fnext()`, which skips any fields in the current record, and goes to the start of the next record.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the issues concerning string lengths and int data type in contrast to string initialisation (as mentioned in the comments), the following comparison function should solve your problem. The idea is to set up a cascade of calls to the other comparison functions as long as they compare equal:

```
int comp_sku_plant_age(const void *a, const void *b) {
    int result;
    if (!(result=comp_sku(a, b))) {
        if (!(result=comp_plant(a, b))) {
            result=comp_age(a, b);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```